# Spectral measure for a finite set of mutually commuting normal operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

The following question is from Exercise $\S 11.11$ in **A Course in Operator Theory** written by *John B. Conway*:

> Suppose $\{N_1, \cdots, N_p\}$ is a finite set of mutually commuting normal operators in $B(H)$ such that for each $1\leq j, k\leq p$, $N_j N_k^* = N_k^* N_j$. Show that there is a unique spectral measure $E$ defined on a compact subset $X$ of $\mathbb{C}^p$ such that for each $1\leq k \leq p$, we have $$N_k = \int_X z_k\,d E(z)$$ where, for each $z\in\mathbb{C}^p$, $z_k$ is the $k$-the coordinate of $z$

My attempt is to apply the definition of **joint spectrum** introduced in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051935). The definition is that, given a $n$-tuple of commuting normal operators $\{N_1, \cdots, N_p\}$, we say a point $z\in\mathbb{C}^p$ is in their joint spectrum iff for any $U_1, \cdots, U_p, V_1, \cdots, V_p\in B(H)$, we have:

$$
\sum_{i\leq p}U_i (z_i - N_i)\neq I_H,\hspace{1cm} \sum_{i \leq p}(z_i - N_i)V_i \neq I_H
$$

If we use $\Sigma$ to denote the joint spectrum of $\{N_1, \cdots, N_p\}$, whenever $\lambda-N_k$ is invertible, we then have:

$$
(0, 0, \cdots, \lambda, 0, \cdots, 0)\in \mathbb{C}\backslash\Sigma \hspace{0.5cm}\implies\hspace{0.5cm} \lambda\in P_k(\mathbb{C}\backslash\Sigma) \hspace{0.5cm}\implies\hspace{0.5cm} P_k(\Sigma)\subseteq\sigma(N_k) \hspace{0.5cm}\implies\hspace{0.5cm} \Sigma\subseteq\times_{k=1}^p\sigma(N_k)
$$

Then, my questions are:

1. How to show $\Sigma$ is closed? (**p.s.** later in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123670900558) I found a proof).
2. How to define the desired spectral measure $E$ on $\Sigma$ such that $N_k = \int_{\Sigma}z_k\,d E(z)$ (since possibly $P_k(\Sigma)$ might be properly contained in $\sigma(N_k)$)? When will $\Sigma$ be equal to $\times_{k=1}^p\sigma(N_k)$?
3. Is there a normal operator $M$ defined on another Hilbert space such that the spectral measure of $M$ coincides with the $E$?